# Proof using well ordering principle

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification

Assume that the set $I \subseteq\mathbb{Z}$ satisfies the following properties:

a.) There exists $n \in I$ such that $n \neq 0$

b.) If $m,n \in I$ , then $m+n \in I$

c.) If $m \in I$ and $a \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $am \in I$

This was a hint that was given: Let $J = (m \in I : m >0)$

Prove that there exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{Z}$, such that $I = (kn_0 | k \in \mathbb{Z})$

Seeing as this is from the section of number theory, specifically division algorithm and well ordering principle, I would imagine those are what I am expected to use.

Intuitively I believe this could be proven by contradiction, but I have no clue how to start and what to do.

Can someone help?

Comment: You provided your assumptions, but I don't see what you're trying to prove from those assumptions.  Would you edit your question to clarify that?  (By the way, these assumptions make the set $I$ an "ideal" of the ring of integers.)

Comment: Ah so sorry, I forgot to show "what to prove". Thanks for pointing that out. Will edit now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess you've been asked to prove that $I$ is the set of all multiples of $k$ for some $0 \lt k \in \Bbb Z$.

First, assumption a tells us that for some $n \neq 0, n \in I$.  Note that either $n \gt 0$ or $-n \gt 0$ and if $n \in I$, then assumption c tells us also $-n = -1 \cdot n \in I$, so now we know $\exists n \gt 0$ with $n \in I$.

Let $k$ be the least positive element of $I$.  Such an element has to exist because the positive integers are well ordered and we've just demonstrated that the set of positive elements of $I$ is non-empty.  Claim:  $I = \{km~|~m \in \Bbb Z\},$ which we'll denote by $k \Bbb Z.$  We'll prove this by showing $k \Bbb Z \subseteq I$ and $I \subseteq k \Bbb Z$.

Assumption c tells us that $k \Bbb Z \subseteq I$ because we know that $k \in I$ so assumption c tells us any multiple of $k$ is in $I$.

Choose $n \in I$ and assume $n \gt 0$.  We want to prove $n \in k \Bbb Z$.  For some $q, r \in \Bbb Z, n = qk+r$ with $0 \leq r \lt k$ -- that's the Euclidean division algorithm.  (If you haven't already proved this fact, it can also be proved in a similar manner to the proof below.)  We know that $qk \in I$, so $-qk \in I$ and assumption b tells us $n-qk=r \in I$.  But $k$ was the smallest positive element of $I$, so that $0 \leq r \lt k$ and $r \in I$ forces $r=0$, which in turn means $n=qk \in k \Bbb Z$.  If $n \lt 0$ and $n \in I$, perform the same analysis on $-n$.  Thus, we conclude $I \subseteq k \Bbb Z$, completing the proof.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How did you come to the conclusion that $ -n > 0$

Comment: If $n \neq 0$, then either $n \gt 0$ or $-n \gt 0$.  That's all I'm saying.

Comment: I am reading and rereading your proof. Honestly, I sort of get it. I'm a math and stats major but this is my first mathematical proof class and its soo over my head. Especially this proof.Perhaps it's normal for beginner like myself.

Comment: It's a way that the well-ordering principle is often used.  First, demonstrate that some well-ordered set of interest is non-empty.  Second, consider the smallest member of that set (which the well-ordering principle tells you has to exist).  Third, demonstrate that if what you're trying to prove weren't true, it would lead to an element of your well-ordered set that is even smaller than the element you already decided was the smallest element.  Fourth, conclude that what you're trying to prove must therefore be true.  But since this is your first proof class, I'll add a little elaboration.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Robert. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with Bezout's Lemma?

If $m,n \in I\subset \mathbb Z$ there are $a,b \in \mathbb Z$ so that $am + bn =\gcd(m,n)$.  Now c; says that $am, bn \in I$ and b; says that $am + bn = \gcd(m,n) \in I$.

Now take the hint:  $J \subset \mathbb N$ and $J$ is not empty (because an $n \ne 0$ is in $I$ and $(-1)n \in I$ so $\pm n \in I$ and one of $n, -n$ must be positive.)  So $J$ has a least element, $n_0$.

If we take any *other* element $n \in I$ then $\gcd(n_0, n)\in I$.  But... $0 < \gcd(n_0, n) \le n_0$.  But $n_0$ is the least positive value so $\gcd(n_0, n) < n_0$ is impossible.  So $\gcd(n_0, n) = n_0$.  So all $n\in I$ are multiples of $n_0$ and $I\subset \{kn_0|k\in \mathbb Z\}$.

And by c; $\{kn_0|k\in \mathbb Z\} \subset I$.

So $\{kn_0|k\in \mathbb Z\}=I$.